# Delta is not working in AWS Glue 4.0 version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Delta Lake is not working with Glue 4.0.
Glue 3.0 is working with delta-core_2.12-1.0.1.jar perfectly.
Which delta-core is supported by Glue 4.0?

I have tried most of them current delta-cor jars but received several error messages..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Glue 4.0 [supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format-delta-lake.html) only version 2.1.0 to my knowledge, since it runs Spark 3.3.